# ogr2ogr difference between -a_srs and -s_srs

Tags: ogr2ogr

What's the difference between the two flags `-a_srs` and `-s_srs`.
From what I read they both define the EPSG the Input-File has. When using `-s_srs` ogr2ogr says that `-t_srs` must be used as well.
But when setting `-a_srs` instead of `-s_srs` it runs without `-t_srs`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [ogr2ogr page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html):

```
-a_srs srs_def: Assign an output SRS
-t_srs srs_def: Reproject/transform to this SRS on output
-s_srs srs_def: Override source SRS
```

So we can see they have very different functions. `-s_srs` tells OGR to ignore the SRS that the input source claims to have and use the one provided. This is useful when OGR is unable to determine the SRS of an input or it is just plain wrong. `-a_srs` sets the provided SRS of the output source (and again assumes you know what you are doing). `-t_srs` instructs `ogr2ogr` to reproject the data but to do this it must know what the input SRS is.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I still don't get why I can't use the `-s_srs` without the `-t_srs` because I think it should just assume that the target srs should be the same like the input .. Giving the source srs should (in my thinking) be optional and not affect the output.

Comment: we'd probably need to see the whole command line to answer that

Comment: `ogr2ogr.exe -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Plugin_new\Shapefiles_Karte\Landkreise\Bundeslaender.geojson" "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Plugin_new\Shapefiles_Karte\Landkreise\Bundeslaender.shp" -s_srs "EPSG:3068" -overwrite` So I would assume that ogr should create the output as well as EPSG:3068 ...

Comment: by default GeoJSON is in epsg:4326

Comment: ah ok .. didn't knew this. And I mean it's no problem to set the t_srs as well. I was just curious about it