# DXF to GeoJSON issue

Tags: shapefile, geojson, dxf

I'm trying to convert DXF file to GeoJSON.

```
Layer name: entities
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Warning 1: One or several characters couldn't be converted correctly from CP1254 to UTF-8.  This warning will not be emitted anymore
Feature Count: 532142
Extent: (0.000000, 0.000000) - (415618.052542, 4548471.567554)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Layer: String (0.0)
PaperSpace: Integer(Boolean) (0.0)
SubClasses: String (0.0)
Linetype: String (0.0)
EntityHandle: String (0.0)
Text: String (0.0)
```

This the ogrinfo result. What would be the correct -s_srs parameters?

Answer (score 1):

please see this answer:
[ogr2ogr difference between -a_srs and -s_srs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202007/ogr2ogr-difference-between-a-srs-and-s-srs)
I assume you already know the SRS of the DXF elements? Judging from the extent maybe it's a projection, maybe the official one in Turkey?
What's the issue here - unknown SRS or you get errors when trying to convert?

P.S. I wanted to comment, but I'm not allowed.

Comment: to comment you need a rep of 50+ https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: I'm actually converting. Then I convert the x y points to latitude and longitude and it doesn't show where it should be on the map. It appears in other countries.

Comment: Have you tried swapping X and Y? Or you don't know the spatial reference of the input?

Comment: Yeah I tried. I dont know :(